# hiding API keys in public github repo in iOS

Tags: ios, github, api-key

Im using the parse framework in my app which I want to put on github in a public repo. Ive got some parse API keys in my app delegate that I dont want others to be able to use. This is my first app and im not really sure how to "hide" them. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: See also [Accidental API Key Exposure is a Major Problem](http://rosspenman.com/api-key-exposure/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in a external file that you never commit. that's most convenient IMO.

e.g. have a keys.plist and in the appDelegate, just read the keys.plist

---

Of course another way that is quite error prone is to blank them using *** before you commit your source but... nah.. :P

Comment: Alright thanks, this seems like the way to do it. I'll just put that plist in gitignore so it's never committed. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Put them in a Plist, give instructions to fill it up  and blank your own key out. Or better still, prompt the user for the API key i a one time routine to create the Plist

Comment: prompt the end-user? aeh.... sounds weird. I would want the api keys as part of the shipped bundle...

Comment: ok I see, I have an app that requires users to subscribe to a 3rd party web service individually I was thinking of that.